CASTEP to Quantum ESPRESSO input parameters table / converter
I am porting some old inputs from CASTEP to QuantumESPRESSO. I am googling for a good reference table comparing the input keywords from both programs, but I am finding nothing at all. I was thinking of something like QE PW input description, but comparing the keywords with those of different programs. Yes, I know not all keywords will even exist on different programs, but the most relevant ones (thresholds, etc) surely are, right?.
Do you know of anything like that? Thanks in advance!

Have you tried ASE? Both packages have a lot of keywords and documentation. Perhaps if you said which keywords in particular you're interested in, that would be easier to answer. I'm usually trying to do this the other way around :)

I tried ASE but I only managed to port the crystal structure, not the whole inputs. The same happened with cif2cell (which in fact showed less rounding errors), but no luck with the input parameters yet...
